# Eclipse PostgreSQL JDBC ping fails

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, eclipse, jdbc

In Eclipse I am trying to set up a PostgreSQL JDBC connection and do a ping.  The ping fails with the error message shown below.  How can I fix it to make it work?

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The authentication type 10 is not supported. Check that you have configured the pg_hba.conf file to include the client's IP address or subnet, and that it is using an authentication scheme supported by the driver.
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:403)
    at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:108)
    at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:66)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:125)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.<init>(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:30)
    at org.postgresql.jdbc3.Jdbc3Connection.<init>(Jdbc3Connection.java:24)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:393)
    at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:267)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.internal.postgresql.PostgreSQLJDBCConnection.createConnection(PostgreSQLJDBCConnection.java:87)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.internalCreateConnection(DriverConnectionBase.java:105)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.DriverConnectionBase.open(DriverConnectionBase.java:54)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.internal.postgresql.PostgreSQLJDBCConnection.<init>(PostgreSQLJDBCConnection.java:47)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.enablement.internal.postgresql.PostgreSQLConnectionFactory.createConnection(PostgreSQLConnectionFactory.java:51)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionFactoryProvider.createConnection(ConnectionFactoryProvider.java:83)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.internal.ConnectionProfile.createConnection(ConnectionProfile.java:359)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.createTestConnection(PingJob.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.datatools.connectivity.ui.PingJob.run(PingJob.java:59)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)
```

I confiigured both JDBC 3 and 4 connections in Eclipse, but both fail.

However, accessing the target PostgreSQL database using the psql from the command line works fine.

Furthermore, accessing the target PostgreSQL database using JDBC through the Squirrel SQL Java-based SQL client also works.

---

**UPDATE**

Accessing the same PostgreSQL database via the [Data Source Explorer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T11Sh.png) produces the above error.  Note that if you code the JDBC access as in the answer below the program works, but this view does not.

Comment: You want a type 4 connection. Type 3 is a largely archaic model. It may be entirely archaic at this point. It involved a native driver bridge. Posting the actual settings you're trying (a URL) might help.

Answer (score 0):

The error message indicates that the authentication type 10 is not supported. You need to check whether the authentication scheme used by the driver is supported by the PostgreSQL server. You also need to ensure that the pg_hba.conf file has been configured to include the client's IP address or subnet.

You can try changing the authentication method used by PostgreSQL by modifying the pg_hba.conf file. Here's a sample configuration that allows all clients from the local network to connect using password authentication:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD  
host    all             all             192.168.0.0/24          md5
```

In this example, clients in the 192.168.0.0/24 subnet are allowed to connect to any database as any user using the md5 authentication method.

You can find more information about configuring the pg_hba.conf file in the PostgreSQL documentation: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html

You may also want to check that the JDBC driver you are using is compatible with your version of PostgreSQL. You can download the latest JDBC driver for PostgreSQL from the official website: https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html

Finally, here is a sample code to connect to a PostgreSQL database using JDBC:

```java
import java.sql.Connection;  
import java.sql.DriverManager;  
import java.sql.SQLException;  
   
public class PostgreSQLJDBC {  
   public static void main(String[] args) {  
      Connection connection = null;  
      try {  
         // Load the PostgreSQL JDBC driver  
         Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");  
  
         // Create a connection to the database  
         String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydatabase";  
         String user = "myuser";  
         String password = "mypassword";  
         connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);  
  
         // Test the connection  
         if (connection != null) {  
            System.out.println("Connected to the database!");  
         } else {  
            System.out.println("Failed to make connection!");  
         }  
      } catch (SQLException e) {  
         System.err.format("SQL State: %s\n%s", e.getSQLState(), e.getMessage());  
      } catch (Exception e) {  
         e.printStackTrace();  
      } finally {  
         try {  
            if (connection != null)  
               connection.close();  
         } catch (SQLException e) {  
            e.printStackTrace();  
         }  
      }  
   }  
}
```

Replace mydatabase, myuser, and mypassword with the appropriate values for your database.

Comment: Thank you for your source code.  It works, and helps to illuminate where I am actually having trouble.  I will see if I can update my original post to show what I mean.